# Deadlock Error in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, deadlock

I have a SSIS package in SQL Server 2008. It has several tasks running in parallel. These jobs are Data Flow tasks and Script tasks. All these tasks are inserting/updating data on common tables. All the tasks are doing insert/update on very large data. Everything was working fine but a few days ago the package started failing with following error.

" Transaction (Process ID 67) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim"

Kindly Suggest.

Comment: Not sure how your package has been designed, but having a lot of parallels usually does not harm SSIS. Can you post the whole of the error message and where (DFT, Sequence container etc.) this is happening.

Comment: I have a sequence container that consists of multiple DFT's and script tasks. Error is caused at DFT's or script tasks.

Comment: Now my other question is, do all these DFT's point to the same database table? Did you check your system logs to see if there's anything that looks out of the normal?

Comment: Yes all the DFT's point to same database tables. They may approach the tables not at the same time. But If I run my tasks in a sequence then it works fine.

Comment: I have experienced something similar before but that was while trying to write the data to 2 excel sheets (within the same book) simultaneously. My only suggestion would be to sequentially execute your DFT's to avoid any potential deadlocks.